# Как привязывают несколько доменов к одному VPS?

Tags: домен, vps, dns, debian

**Суть:** Поставить на свой VPS несколько сайтов, и при этом иметь к ним доступ по разным доменам.

**Что имею:** Debian6, LAMP, Домен зарегистрированный у регистратора

Как это реализуется? Используются ли свои DNS сервера или можно использовать сервера регистратора?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прописываете нужные DNS записи, на сервере апачем, раз уж он у вас всё равно в связке присутствует, [разруливаете запросы по доменам](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/). Всё.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 0):

dns то можешь любой оставить, хоть регистратора, хоть свой. Главное A-запись на свой сервер направь, ну и как сказал оратор выше, разруливай входящие запросы апачем. Виртуальные хосты тебе в помощь.